# Creating Cordova Project with 5.1.1

Tags: ios, cordova

I had some issues with Ajax call on Cordova-iOS project and I was trying to upgrade the project to the latest cordova. The old one is cordova version 3.8.0.

I have upgraded my cordova to 5.1.1 (latest at this time) but when I created the project from scratch it shows cordova-ios@3.8.0. Shouldn't it be cordova-ios@5.1.1?

See the command outputs below. I don't understand it. How can I create a new project with cordova 5.1.1?

abcd:bby511 me$ npm -v
2.10.0

abcd:bby511 me$ cordova -v
5.1.1

abcd:bby511 me$ cordova platform update ios
Updating ios project...
iOS project updated with cordova-ios@3.8.0

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, you have updated Cordova version to 5.1.1, but this is the Cordova CLI number version, not every Cordova platform version.

The last ios platform version (stable) is the 3.8, so your project is updated correctly. You can check every platform status at their git page, for instance for iOS: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios

Regards.

Comment: I was trying to install the Cordova plugin (cordova-plugin-whitelist) but getting this error:

Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 3.8.0, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev

What does that mean?